# Interacting with elements from FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

I have implemented a FragmentPagerAdapter with 4 tabs and I have associated a fragment to each of them. The problem is that I can not interact with the elements they contain, I tried the following:

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

        // Some codes for layout such as findViewById
        ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        img.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.i("Fragment", "This is a test"); 
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

This method is in the class that inherits from 'Fragment' and load one of the layouts, having 4 classes of the same type as this, one for each tab.

Fails in the method 'findViewById', but if I can not put it out there where do I put it?

Thank you very much.

Continuing with the example I have a new problem emerged.
One of the views loads a GridView with images as follows:

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.init, container, false);

        final GridView grid = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.myGrid);            
        grid.setNumColumns(2);
        grid.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        return view;
    }
```

The problem is that the method 'new ImageAdapter(context)' receives as a parameter a variable type Context to load in method 'newImageView (context)' that it needs this type of variable and passing 'this' the variable is type Fragment but not Context, by what fails, how I can fix?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are accessing any widget from an inflated view you must get them with respect that view only

Change this line

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
```

to this

```
 ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
```

comment me about the result

Comment: OK, fine. Now it works.

Have much logic you've said and I do not know if I would have noticed, thank you very much.